# Private property, "package" setter

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to hide the setter of a @property for a header I'm making publicly available in a framework I'm building:

```
//File: X.h
@interface X 
@property (nonatomic,readonly, strong) NSString* identifier;
@end
```

I have a category that adds some methods to this interface:

```
//File: X+implementation.h
@interface X (Implementation)
...
@end
```

This category is only accessible under my project, i.e. I'm not making it public it when I'm building the framework. Many sources say that I should add a interface extension with the readwrite property, but this is useless since my category wont be able to see the readwrite definition on "X.m". So I thought to add it on the category declaration:

```
//File: X+implementation.h
@interface X ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSString* identifier;
@end
//same file
@interface X (Implementation)
...
@end
```

this compiles but gives me a **[X setIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I've tried to replicate the extension on X.m, to manually create the setters under X.m, to manually @synthesize the variable but none of those seems to work. What should I do in this case?

Comment: In `File: X+implementation.h` the interface needs to be `@interface X (Implementation)` not `@interface X ()`

Comment: Hi Oliver, If you see, the @interface X (Implementation) is defined too, just under the extension, after the //same file comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In X.h declare the read only property as usual.

```
@interface X : XSuperclass
@property (nonatomic,readonly, strong) NSString* identifier;
@end
```

In X.m, redefine the property as readwrite in the class extension. This will still subject the property to auto synthesis, thus providing an implementation of the setter.

```
@interface X ()
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, strong) NSString* identifier;
@end

@implementation X
// Your class's main implementation
@end
```

In your category's implementation file, declare - but do not implement - a different category only visible to your category. Re-declare the property as readwrite there:

```
@interface X (CategoryPrivate)
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, strong) NSString* identifier;
@end

@implementation X (Category)

// your category impl here
- (void)methodName {
    self.identifier = @"id";
}

@end
```

This does have maintainability issues due to the duplicate declaration of the readwrite property. But it does take overall less code and possible confusion than other ways to implement this.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Just out of curiosity, what are the other alternatives to implement the same feature?

Comment: Two methods in particular I was thinking of 1) manually implementing the setter in the private category 2) have a whole separate header and category with implementations for 'private' functionality. Not too radically different than this approach really, just differently organized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the property to be readonly, you shouldnt have to use a Category for that.

**Header**:

```
@interface X : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *identifier;

@end
```

---

**Implementation**:

```
@interface X ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *identifier;

@end

@implementation X

//.. your implementation goes here

@end
```